# MySQL "CREATE TABLE LIKE" include triggers

Tags: mysql, trigger, ctas

I'm using MySQL 5.6 (5.6.29-76.2-56-log Percona XtraDB Cluster)

When I issue a `CREATE TABLE LIKE` the triggers on the tables are not copied - is it possible to get them on the new table as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long and the short answer is no! This is yet another "non-feature" of MySQL. This construct is known more commonly as CTAS (`CREATE TABLE AS.... SELECT`) - the `CREATE TABLE LIKE` syntax is non-standard - like so much of MySQL!

MySQL's documentation argues [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html) - that this lacuna is to ensure "flexibility" - you'd laugh if it wasn't so sad!

> CREATE TABLE ... SELECT does not automatically create any indexes for
>   you. This is done intentionally to make the statement as flexible as
>   possible.

You can create them (indexes) by declaring them before the `SELECT` as follows

> If you want to have indexes in the created table, you should specify
>   these before the SELECT statement:

```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE bar (UNIQUE (n)) SELECT n FROM foo;
```

But you're out of luck for `TRIGGER`s, `FUNCTION`s and `STORED PROCEDURE`s.

If this is important to you, you could try your luck with PostgreSQL - which has a table inheritance mechanism, whereby schema changes are propaged, but I can't see why a WITH `INDEXES`, WITH `FUNCTIONS`, WITH `STORED PROCEDURES` syntax couldn't be introduced.

If you put in a feature request (good luck with that! MySQL doesn't even have `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s yet), I'd be happy to file a `"me-too"` if you post the link back here for my attention.

The `CREATE TABLE LIKE` is a similarly crippled option - from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html):

> CREATE TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve any DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX
>   DIRECTORY table options that were specified for the original table, or
>   any foreign key definitions.

Comment: A side note: Postgres does have an option to copy indexes when using `create table like` but there is no way functions _can_ be included as there is no real direct dependency between a function and a table (like e.g. between a trigger and a table). But theoretically triggers (actually the trigger _definition) _could_ be included though